# Connecting SIM800A to Raspberry Pi Zero WH with RS232

Tags: pi-zero-w, uart, gsm

I'm trying to set up a very simple mobile proxy server using a Raspberry Pi Zero WH and a SIM800A GSM Module. The particular module I seem to have has an RS232 port as well as described in the picture.

Can I connect the raspberry pi to the sim module using a RS232 to USB convertor? I only see guides about using jumper wires and connecting the TX of Raspberry to RX of Sim and vice versa. Just curious why no one used the RS232 port. Is there an obvious thing I'm missing or is the RS232 port not very common with most modules.

[image]